# parsing email body with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string

Edit: I use IMAP.php library to get the email information into array() (header,l body, subject etc).

I have this email [body] to extract some information on it :

```
Dear Recruiter,

You have received an application for the position of Software Engineer(Ref: 1266). See below for details...

-------------------------------------------------------


COVER LETTER

I have just viewed your job vacancy for 'Software Engineer' (203010236) on *******.co.uk and would like to be considered for this position.

Please find a copy of my CV attached.

Arteni Georgica

------------------------------------------------------

You can view this CV online at http://www.******.co.uk/cgi-bin/login/details.cgi?ref=10137329

Additional candidate info:

Jobtitle:  Web Developer
Location:  Enfield, Hertfordshire
Travel:    10 miles
Temp/Perm: Permanent


This application has been sent via *******.co.uk
```

I need to extract with PHP this block of information into an array Key => Value :

```
    Jobtitle:  Web Developer
    Location:  Enfield, Hertfordshire
    Travel:    10 miles
    Temp/Perm: Permanent
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've done so far?

Comment: **Hint: `You can use DOMDocument`**

Comment: I've edit my question.Sorry - I use IMAP.php library to get the email information into array() (header,body, subject etc) .I need to parse arr['body']

Comment: Hint: You cannot use DOMDocument with text email or a MIME email which has not yet been parsed to extract an inline HTML block.

Comment: If the formatting is always going to be consistent, then this should be fairly easy to do with a bit of simple sub-string matching. Split it into lines and look for the field names.

Comment: still working on it ... I'll come back.

Comment: Hi again I've use nl2br() to break lines from that plain text email body than line by line I use Simba suggestion sub-string matching... Thank you!